# Валидация поля регулярным выражения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Номер заказа имеет форму:

```
  SP4RK-XXXXX
```

где

```
 0<X<=9 (от 0 до 9)
```

Начальное

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Будет ли данное выражение работать?

```
^[s,p,r,kS,P,R,K0-9]+$
```

И как задать тире `-`?

Comment: дак возьмите да проверьте будет или нет https://regex101.com/r/4xbjZ0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если длина обеих частей (до и после дефиса) всегда равна пяти, то:

```
/^\w{5}-\d{5}$/
```

А в случае произвольной длины (1..Infinity):

```
/^\w+-\d+$/
```

Или, в случае если первая часть всегда `SP4RK`:

```
/^SP4RK-\d{5}$/i
```

---

При использовании в атрибуте `pattern`, заключать регулярку в символы `/` не нужно.

Comment: я так понял, что там в целом первая часть всегда `SP4RK-`

Comment: @teran, и правда, возможно... из вопроса не определить, поэтому дополнил ответ, на всякий случай :) Спасибо за подсказку.